# Disable Maven dependency mediation

Tags: java, maven

As I don't trust Maven to pick the "best" version for me in dependency mediation, I would like to fail the build if there is a version conflict that is not explicitly fixed in the pom (usually by using dependencyManagement).

The dependencyConvergence rule of the enforcer plugin seemed to be what I was looking for, but unfortunately, it cannot handle *-exludes (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-195), so I cannot really use it.

Is there any other way to stop Maven from applying the "nearest dependency wins rule" but make the owner of the pom decide which version to use?

Comment: I'd say the only way to do so is to manually exclude either all transitive dependencies, but one required, or manually exclude everything and manually add particular version to the pom.

Comment: @evgenii No. The best ways that came up so far are either to completely avoid *-exclusions, or to fix the dependencyConvergence rule (as kriegaex said, there is already a pull request, but it needs to be properly tested). I still hope for something better (some solution which has reached beta or release state).

Comment: If i have correctly understand the problem, you want to stop the maven auto transitive resolution and decide the version of the transitive your self to avoid conflicts with your own managed dependencies. so please provide the dimension of your configuration. There is many ways to solve this, but its depends on your situation.

Comment: - If you have 2 conflicting transitive dependencies " use dependencyManagement " as you mentioned above to control the version of the transitive dependencies.   - IF you don't like the Transitive deps at all just exclude it "<exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>"

Comment: The problem is not in my own project. I am responsible to provide a parent pom (and configure plugins) for 100+ developers. I need a reliable method that works out of the box (the enforcer plugin would be something like this if somebody wrote an official fix of the *-exclude problem)

Comment: Do you have to use Maven? It works well for 'standard configurations' but when you need something custom it really slows you down...

Comment: @AlexNikolaenkov Yes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) and fail the build if [`dependencyConvergence`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) is violated. Give it a shot and see if it does what you want.

**Update:** Sorry, I just noticed that you tried and are having a problem with excludes. Have you tried to build the plugin with the pull request from the linked ticket and see if it fixes the problem for you?

Comment: If I find nothing else, I'll give it a try. But because there are lot of edge cases (like the one in the question) and I write a parent pom for 100+ developers, it would require a lot of testing before I roll out such an "unofficial version".

Comment: Well, the "official" version seems to be buggy, so maybe you are better off with a (yet "unofficial") patch for that version. But of course, thorough testing is definitely a prudent decision. You could run both versions for your huge parent POM and see if it a) fixes your known problem and b) shows any regressions for previously correct results. I just wanted to help, I have not tested that pull request myself either.

Answer (score 1):

You can define explicitly which version Maven should use by using [dependency version ranges](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges).

Basically you just need to surround your version with round brackets (exclusive quantifier) or square brackets (inclusive quantifier).

For example:

```
<version>[4.2]</version>
```

would mean: use exactly version 4.2 and nothing else.

Or:

```
<version>[4.2,)</version>
```

would mean: use version 4.2 or higher.

Or:

```
<version>(,4.2]</version>
```

would mean: use a version below or exactly 4.2.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I want. My concern are transitive dependencies which appear in more than one version.